# Monitor data usage for multiple iOS devices

Tags: ios, monitoring, bandwidth

What I have:

- iPhone 5s running 7.0.4 (jailbroken)
- iPad 3rd gen running 7.1
- iPad mini running 7+ (not 100% on this one, it's my girlfriend's iPad)

All of the devices are on my AT&T account.

What I want:
An app to monitor all of the data usage for all of the devices on one device with notifications (preferably on my 5s).

I am currently using an app called [My Data Manager](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-data-manager-track-your/id477865384?mt=8), which gives alerts for the device it is on. I also use the [My ATT](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myat-t/id309172177?mt=8) app, which gives data usage for all devices, but does not have notifications. Most likely, it will be an app that will require me to enter my AT&T account information. Any recommendations?

Comment: Data usage over cellular, not WiFi, correct?

Comment: Correct...but. I would prefer the app to do both, at least for the device I am on, but the My Data Manager already does that for my 5s, so it's not necessary.